# Shockwave object For Windows Ce

Tags: c#, flash, adobe, compact-framework, windows-ce

I can use Shockwave Flash object in C# windows application 
How can I use Shockwave object in Windows embebde Ce 6.0 CF 2.0 or Is there another way 
for animation in Windows ce.

Comment: im not sure if it helps, look at silverlight, thats windows version of flash. animations etc.. and couple of years ago i made a c# program with flash embedded into by importing the libs from, web .net services or something like that, this allowed me to compile a exe than open a flash animation as a normal program, basically making the flash independent like adobe air all necessary files to run were embedded into the exe

Answer (score 0):

As far as Flash on Windows CE 6 - I believe there is only very limited support in the form of Flash Lite for CE 6.0 R3 (and I have no idea if you can still get hold of it) and nothing at all for before that.

Comment: Flash Player did exist for PocketPC 2000, it was a cut down version of Flash Player 4 and released in 2001. That's CE 3. Of course this was long before Flash got all these features for video and 3D geometry.